# PHP how to replace the exact words in a string

Tags: php, replace

I have this php code

```
 $filename = "verbs.php"; //  http://alylores.x10.mx/vega/verbs2.php  
 $handle = fopen($filename, "r");  
 $verbs = fread($handle, filesize($filename));  
 fclose($handle);
```

and i used PHP `explode()` function

to split the words into array

`$verbslist = explode(",", $verbs);`

and i also have a string, like:

`$sentence = "Where is Phisz' dog?";`

and then i used the `str_replace()` function to remove the verbs and some specifice words from the sentence, so that the only left will be the subject(s).

`$newsentence  = str_replace($verbslist,"",$sentence);`

but the result is:

new Sentence: `Phz' dog?` // the `is` on `Phisz` was also removed.

and i figured out that the problem is that the `Phisz` words contain `is` which was also removed with the `str_replace()`.

what i want is how can i remove the words/vebs from the sentence without affecting other words. I mean removing the **EXACT** VERB/WORD..... and in case insensitive...

that the expected result will be like this

new Sentence: `Phisz' dog?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a regular expression like `/\bword\b/` will replace only the word as a whole. `\b` denotes a word boundary. So you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($verblist as &$verb) {
    $verb = '/\b' . preg_quote($verb, '/') . '\b/';
}

$newsentence = preg_replace($verblist, '', $sentence);
```

Comment: you want to also use `preg_quote()` on `$verb` in case a word contains meta characters

Comment: your answer gives me the point sir... thanks... however i found this also....$verbslist = str_replace(",","|", $verbs);



$pattern = "/\b(".$verbslist.")\b/i";
$newq2 = preg_replace($pattern, "", $newq);

Comment: Don't forget to `unset($verb)` after the `foreach` loop to prevent undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to remove exact verbs you can put spaces around each of your verbs so your list would be something like this with _ denoting a space

```
" is "
" where "
```

etc.

Then to get case insensitive make all your verbs lower case and then wrap your verbs in the strtolower()

```
strtolower($sentence)
```

So your replace would look something like this:

```
$newsentence = str_replace($verbslist,"",strtolower($sentence));
```

Comment: sir... why i want to find some automatic ways, coz that is very time consuming... and no guarantee that works well.. coz... that will not work with the first word and last word.... and my verbslist is very long to add space in every one of it...

Comment: This would miss the verbs followed by punctuation, like "Who cares?" or "I drink, but I'm not a drunk."